# How to handle nested data modeling DynamoDB?

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I searched for this question, but couldn't find specifically what I was looking for.

Say you have a team model:

```
{
  "partitionKey": "#team",
  "rangeKey": "teamLocation_teamId_...",
  "members": [
    {
      "firstName": "Michael",
      "lastName": "Scott"
    },
    {
        ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Easy enough, I can find the team, and it's members. So each member of the team would also be a user. They would have their own entry on the table as a user:

```
{
  "partitionKey": "emailAddress",
  "rangeKey": "...",
  "firstName": "Michael",
  "lastName": "Scott"
}
```

Say a user changes their last name. Do you have to find the team they're on, manually change the team by finding the user and updating the last name? The SQL way would reference the user table inside of the team, so whenever you get the Team, you get the most up to date version of the member.

I guess my question is: when you are attaching relational fields to the document type storage, how do you best deal with updates to the values you've attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should ask whether you really need the data with the other objects. It's not uncommon to do so in a NoSQL database, so I'll assume you do. With that assumption in mind you need to figure out how best to structure your data to allow the updates in as efficient a manor as possible. My typically approach to updating data in other rows of the same table is to use DynamoDB streams and lambda. That does still require that you have a way of finding the rows you want to update, and this is where your storage structure may not be the best idea. Here is what I would recommend for your case. I'm going to make some assumptions to simplify, hopefully you can take it from there.

- One row in the table for the team. This includes any information you need to store about the team *except* the members. The team identifier is the partition key, with some other fixed text as the sort key (e.g. 'TeamInfo').
- One row in the table for each team member. This row should include the team identifier for the partition key, and an identifier for the person in the sort key.
- One row in the table for the person. This record should include the identifier for the person as well as what team the person is on.

When you want to query for a team you ask for all records where the partition key is the team, and assemble those records to return the team, with its team members.

When a person is created/updated/deleted the lambda that is handling streams from the table should create/update/delete the related record for that person within the team. You can find that record (for updates and deletes) by using the team identifier and the person identifier.